# jQuery - Separate li groups based on class location

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I have a group of li episodes. Each group can only have one red class on click, but only from within that group. Each group is defined as shown below (separated into 3 groups) and as follows:

1. li has .newseason and any li after it before hitting newseason again is a group.
2. All lis before first .newseason

html:

```
<ul id="seasons">

<li class="red">Episode 1</li>
<li>Episode 2</li>
<li>Episode 3</li>

<li class="newseason">Episode 1</li>
<li class="red">Episode 2</li>
<li>Episode 3</li>

<li class="newseason">Episode 1</li>
<li>Episode 2</li>
<li class="red">Episode 3</li>
<li>Episode 4</li>

</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$('li').live('click',function(){
//add .red to clicked li in group and remove previous .red from same group
});
```

[Here's the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/89PgF/)

How can each group only have one red class on click, but only from within that group? I want to know how it can be done based on the .newseason class without adding any parent classes. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you seperate your seasons with `<ul>`-Tags?

Comment: @Johannes Klauß I want to know how it can be done based on the .newseason class

Comment: @Wonka - Adeneo is trying to help, and brought up a good issue.  We are all volunteers here, so, making sure the question is clearly asked is a critical part of getting a valid answer.  "How can I get this to work" is very vague.  Being snippy with people who are trying to be helpful is not a good way to get people to help you in the future.

Comment: @adeneo I updated the question, sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: @BrianHoover Thanks for your advice. I made the question clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep all within the same UL Element (like you mentioned), you should do this... http://jsfiddle.net/w8sUz/4/

I'm sure there might be a better / more optimized way to achieve this, but this works.

HTML

```
<ul class="seasons">
  <li class="newseason">Episode 1</li>
  <li class="red">Episode 2</li>
  <li>Episode 3</li>

  <li class="newseason">Episode 1</li>
  <li class="red">Episode 2</li>
  <li>Episode 3</li>

  <li class="newseason">Episode 1</li>
  <li>Episode 2</li>
  <li class="red">Episode 3</li>
  <li>Episode 4</li>
</ul>​
```

JS:

```
$('li').live('click',function(){
    $(this).addClass('red');
    if( !$(this).hasClass('newseason') )
    {
        var prev = $(this).prev();
        while( prev.parent().attr('class') == 'seasons' )
        {
            if( prev.hasClass('red') )
            {
                prev.removeClass('red');
                return true;
            }
            if( prev.hasClass('newseason') )
            {
                break;
            }
            prev = prev.prev();
        }
    }        

    var next = $(this).next();
    while( next.parent().attr('class') == 'seasons' )
    {
        if( next.hasClass('newseason') )
        {
            break;
        }
        if( next.hasClass('red') )
        {
            next.removeClass('red');
            return true;
        }
        next = next.next() ;
    } 
});​
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: No Problem.  May i ask why you have to keep them all within the same UL though?  It would be much simpler to separate them into different UL elements.  Also i think it might give a better UI for the user.

Answer (score 2):

I would go ahead and separate the "groups" into separate UL tags ( as Johannes also suggested above )  making the code look like the following:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Episode 1</li>
    <li>Episode 2</li>
    <li>Episode 3</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>Episode 1</li>
    <li class="red">Episode 2</li>
    <li>Episode 3</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>Episode 1</li>
    <li>Episode 2</li>
    <li class="red">Episode 3</li>
    <li>Episode 4</li>
</ul>​
```

And the JS:

```
$('li').live('click',function(){
    $(this).parent().find('li.red').removeClass('red');
    $(this).addClass('red');
});​
```

You can check it out on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w8sUz/

Comment: I need to do this based on the newseason class. Maybe indexing everything before the 1st .newseason, and then everything after it before hitting the next .newseason?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('li').live('click',function(){
$('.red').removeClass('red');
$(this).addClass('red');
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't take the groups into consideration